# persisting json type val with spring boot application and mysql server

Tags: mysql, json, jpa, spring-boot

I have an Entity class , that one of it members is a simple key/value(string) map.

Im working in **spring boot** context and **MySQL** server, and would like to save this map in a JSON type column.

Is it possible ? I know MySQL just recently started to support JSON type.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: @wogsland , i've visited this link, it just explains about mysql part, not about how to do it from spring boot ..